# Mod_rewrite optional url parameters prevents redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a url that has an optional parameter. The url is `http://example.com/piercing/parameter/value` but the url can also be viewed as `http://example.com/piercing`. I've set the optional parameter in my `mod_rewrite` using:

```
RewriteRule ^piercing/([^/]*)$ piercing.php
RewriteRule ^piercing/location/([^/]*)$ piercing.php?location=$1
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

The problem that I ran into is that I have a redirect set in `mod_rewrite` to redirect users away from certain pages until a specific date and the `piercing.php` page being one of them. Ever since I added that rewrite rule for the optional parameter the redirect doesn't work for that page anymore but it does for all the other pages.

Inside of the redirect I listed the pages I do not want redirected by exluding them from the rule. This is the redirect rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{TIME} <20171201000000
 # DESKTOP
 #RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^00\.000\.00\.00
 # PHONE
 #RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^000\.000\.0\.00
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(styles|images|javascript).+$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !aftercare.php$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !faq.php$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !redirect=(?:construction|404)$ [NC] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|ttf|woff|js) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* index.php?redirect=construction [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

What would stop that page from redirecting since I don't have a rule of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !piercing.php$ [NC]` set?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

add this condition.